# How to make Discord bot create a channel after x amount of time for only one user and staff? - discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot, and I'm having trouble. This bot has a system where it is supposed to create a channel after 15 minutes from one user joining and then sends an embed in this channel. It is a privated channel for only the user and staff. Anyone know how to make this?

I tried to find videos on youtube, and found nothing.

Edit: I just read the Docs and nothing helped me.

What the hell guys? HELP ME PLEASE. THIS IS A HELP WEBSITE NOT A GO DO IT YOURSELF SITE?

Comment: Don't look for YouTube videos. They are all outdated, teach bad code, and don't teach you anything. You'll just be copy-pasting some guy's code, and no one will make a tutorial for exactly the thing you're trying to do. Read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

In your `guildMemberAdd()` event, add a timeout for 15 minutes, and then create the channel:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    member.guild.channels
      .create({
        name: 'example'
      })
      .then((chn) => {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder();
        // embed data here

        // send the embed
        chn.send({ embeds: [embed] });
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }, 900000); // 15 minutes in milliseconds
});
```